# How to execute cluster based bootstrap sampling using boot?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data.frame which has observations sourced from certain clusters. My objective is to obtain a 95% confidence interval of the median of a measurement. In the toy example below, I have 100 observations from 50 clusters. Each cluster contributes to 2 observations. The code below treats all 100 observations as independent when bootstrapping is executed. However, I want to retain the correlations between observations in a cluster since the observations are not really independent in my data. A cluster-based sampling is suitable for this, however I am unsure how to implement this in boot. In the example below, `value` is the value of observation and `cluster_id` is the identifier to the cluster from which the value is sourced. My idea is to generate a bootstrap based 95% CI for the median of `value`.

```
library("boot")
val <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
id <- rep(1:50, 2)
dat <- data.frame("cluster_id" = id, "value" = val)

stat_fun<- function(data, indices){
  b <- data[indices, ]
  return(median(b$value))
}
boot.ci(boot(data = dat, stat_fun, R = 1000), type = "bca")
```

**UPDATE**

This is an update to my first post. I am thinking to force the `boot` function to sample `cluster_id` instead of data.frame `dat` and then using the `stat_fun` return the median of the bootstrap sample. Is this approach correct?

```
library("boot")
val <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
id <- rep(1:50, 2)
dat <- data.frame("cluster_id" = id, "value" = val)
    
statistic_function <- function(cluster_id, indices) {
  cluster_sample <- dat[dat$cluster_id %in% cluster_id[indices],]
  median_value <- median(cluster_sample$value)
  return(median_value)

bootstrap_results <- boot(data = dat$cluster_id, statistic_function, R = 1000)
boot.ci(bootstrap_results, type = "bca", index = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` *values* by `cluster_id`, then `sample` from them with replacement. `quantile(., probs=c(.025, .975)` should give you the percentile-based 95% confidence intervals. Please have this confirmed by a statistician,  especially if there are concerns regarding the use of medians (in contrast to means).

```
> values <- split(dat$value, dat$cluster_id)
> set.seed(42)
> boot_res <- replicate(1e5, median(unlist(values[sample(cl, replace=TRUE)])))
> (res <- c(est=median(dat$value), quantile(boot_res, c(.025, .975))))
      est      2.5%     97.5% 
10.179594  9.707186 10.767397 
> stripchart(res[1], pch=3, xlim=c(9, 11)); arrows(res[2], 1, res[3], 1, length=0)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> dat <- data.frame(cluster_id=rep(1:50, 2), value=rnorm(100, 10, 2))
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, but I am looking for a solution using the boot R package itself. I see an argument named "strata" in the boot function, however it's documentation is sparse.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the bootstrap with *stratified resampling*, and probably you can specify `strata = dat$cluster_id` to make it committed by clusters, for exmaple

```
bootstrap_results <- boot(data = dat, stat_fun, R = 1e3, strata = dat$cluster_id)
```

Comment: I did think this is the way to do it, but it looks like this will only force the boot to sample randomly from each cluster which is not what is required for me. I got this information from this thread here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242404/how-does-the-boot-package-in-r-handle-collecting-bootstrap-samples-if-strata-are

What I require is that when a bootstrap sample is generated, it needs to have all the observations from a cluster, if that cluster is sampled.

Comment: @j1897 so, your bootstrap is for clusters, rather than entries within clusters, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Please check my UPDATE in the original post.